# Generate cURL string representation from libcurl instance

Tags: curl, libcurl, node-libcurl

I was wondering if it is possible to generate `cURL` string from a libcurl instance. For example if I'm using the node binding for libcurl as below,

```
const curl = new Curl();
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.URL, "https://httpbin.org/get");
```

Is it possible to somehow generate the following from this instance?

```
curl https://httpbin.org/get
```

Comment: An alternative approach is to record the full HTTP request that was generated and convert *that* into a curl command line with [h2c](https://curl.haxx.se/h2c/).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with `libcurl` and so it's not possible with the Node.js bindings, `node-libcurl`.

To do that you will need to create a wrapper around the `Curl` instance and keep track of the options being set on it, you can then use that information to build the command line arguments.

*disclaimer: I'm the author of the node.js bindings*

Comment: Thanks @JCM I'll try to follow that approach.